# How to round down only the decimal places

Tags: c#

I'm trying to round the following number as follows:

```
6.89 <- dollars and cents
```

I need to use this number in calculations rounded down to the nearest `10c`.
Therefore I need: `6.80`

To clarify I need a way to obtain the following example results:

```
1.32 --> 1.30  
1.55 --> 1.50  
6.89 --> 6.80
```

I can't seen how this can be done with `Round` or `Floor`.

Comment: So you need to round to 1 d.p.? What's the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't 6.89 round down to 6.80?

Comment: 6.89 --> 6.70? That's odd

Comment: Your first example doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're looking for "Round to Nearest."  See the duplicate I linked; it outlines the general principles.

Comment: Why do you consider the result of `Math.Round(d, 1)` incorrect? As far as I see, it's what you need. Am I wrong?

Comment: No I don't want to display anything - I need to use the figures in calculations

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: As stated below - the dups don't answer my specific question. I didn't realise this was a general principle site ... I thought it was a answers site. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this, I don't see any error with that, and works well with your examples.

Math.Floor (number*10)/10

Comment: use this in case you want to make it a string at the end, string myString = myInt.ToString();

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So many people attack ... and the dup questions aren't even dup. This site has become so poor